# tuple indices typeerror when i call the row

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, folium

I am using folium with a postgreSQL database connected but i have the

> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
import psycopg2 

import folium 

import psycopg2 

conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "databasename", user = "postgres", password = "password", host = "localhost", port = "5432" ) 

print("Base de dados conectado com sucesso")

cur = conn.cursor()
 
cur = conn.cursor()
 
cur.execute('select * from "CADASTRO_USUARIO"')
rows=cur.fetchall()
 
for index, row in cur:
 
rows = (f" {r[6]} {r[7]}")

center = [-8.894870, 13.296380] 

map_angola = folium.Map(location=center, zoom_start=10)

#LINE PRESENTING THE ERROR
folium.Marker([r['{r[6]} {r[7]}']], popup=['Location'], icon=folium.Icon(icon='cloud')).add_to(map_angola)

map_angola.save('Profissionais.html')
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.  The data from PostgreSQL is just overwritten, not shared at all with Folium.  And the indentation is wrong.  And what line is it that throws the indicated error?

Comment: Hi, iam just a biggener in programming but i got this exercise to understand map creation. The line error is line 32

Comment: You don't have a line 32.  Simplifying the program to better isolate the error is fine, but you would then need to accurately convey that simplified program.

Comment: I have put a comment on the error line. Thanks in advance